# How do you make R poly() evaluate (or "predict") multivariate new data (orthogonal or raw)?

Tags: r, regression, polynomials, orthogonal

**With the `poly` function in R, how do I *evaluate* a multivariate polynomial?**

- This post has 4 questions total, highlighted below.
- I'm seeking to evaluate the output of a `poly()`-output object (orthogonal or raw polynomials).  Such would give me the ability to use polynomials to generate a row similar to that of my model matrix that I may use to evaluate a result (i.e., I seek to push multivariate *test data* values through a `poly()` call so that it can be evaluated similarly to a row of my regression's method matrix).
- My background:  I'm relatively new to R, R's `poly()`, and R's regression routines.
- I've tried several approaches and would appreciate help with each:

---

**(A): Direct approach with `predict`**

This method FAILED, apparently due to some unexpected class of the inputs.  I'm aware that these particular x1 & x2 values, being collinear, are not ideal for a general fit (I'm simply trying to get the `predict` machinery operational).  The use of `predict` was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728289/extracting-orthogonal-polynomial-coefficients-from-rs-poly-function) SO post.  **(Q1) Is it possible to call the `predict` method directly to evaluate this polynomial?**

```
> x1 = seq(1,  10,  by=0.2)
> x2 = seq(1.1,10.1,by=0.2)
> t = poly(cbind(x1,x2),degree=2,raw=T)
> predict(t,newdata=data.frame(x1=2.03,x2=2.03))
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

---

**(B) Direct evaluation only works for raw polynomials (not orthogonal)**

Due to (A), I tried a workaround with a direct call to poly().  For *raw* polynomials, I could get it to work, but I had to repeat data for each respective variable.  Following shows (1st) the failure with single data point, (2nd) success with repeating the value.  **(Q2) Is there any way to avoid the redundant repeat of data in the 2nd listing to make raw `poly()` evaluate properly?**

```
> poly(cbind(x1=c(2.03),x2=c(2.13)),degree=2,raw=T)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = apply(z, 1L, function(x) paste(x,  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

> poly(cbind(x1=c(2.03,2.03),x2=c(2.13,2.13)),degree=3,raw=T)
      1.0    2.0      3.0  0.1    1.1      2.1    0.2      1.2      0.3
[1,] 2.03 4.1209 8.365427 2.13 4.3239 8.777517 4.5369 9.209907 9.663597
[2,] 2.03 4.1209 8.365427 2.13 4.3239 8.777517 4.5369 9.209907 9.663597
attr(,"degree")
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 3
```

If I try a similar redundantly-listed-data approach with *orthogonal* polynomials, I incur the "hey, your data's redundant!" error (which I also incur if I only list each variable's value once). **(Q3) Is it possible to evaluate multivariate orthogonal polynomials via a direct call to `poly()`?**

```
> poly(cbind(x1=c(2.03, 2.03),x2=c(2.13, 2.13)),degree=2)
Error in poly(dots[[1L]], degree, raw = raw) : 
  'degree' must be less than number of unique points
```

---

**(C) Inability to extract alpha & norm coefficients from multivariate orthogonal polynomials**
Finally, I'm aware that there is a `coefs` input variable to `predict.poly`.  I understand the `coefs` are to be the alpha and norm values output from an orthogonal polynomial fit.  However, I am only able to extract those from a *univariate* polynomial fit ...  when I fit a *multivariate* orthogonal (or raw), the return value from `poly` does NOT have the coefs.  **(Q4) Is it possible to extract `alpha` and `norm` coefficients from calling `poly()` for an orthogonal polynomial fit to *multivariate* data?**

```
> t = poly(cbind(x1),degree=2)   # univariate orthog poly --> WORKS
> attributes(t)$coefs
$alpha
[1] 5.5 5.5

$norm2
[1]    1.000   46.000  324.300 1826.458


> t = poly(cbind(x1,x2),degree=2)  # multivariate orthog poly --> DOES NOT WORK
> attributes(t)$coefs
NULL
```

Please let me know if I can clarify.  Thank you kindly for any help you can provide.

Comment: I've made a relevant post to the r-help mailing list which you can read via nabble http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/predict-poly-for-multivariate-data-tp4709718.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, it seems that this has been fixed

```
> x1 = seq(1,  10,  by=0.2)
> x2 = seq(1.1,10.1,by=0.2)
> t = poly(cbind(x1,x2),degree=2,raw=T)
> 
> class(t) # has a class now
[1] "poly"   "matrix"
> 
> # does not throw error
> predict(t, newdata = cbind(x1,x2)[1:2, ])                                                     
     1.0  2.0 0.1  1.1  0.2
[1,] 1.0 1.00 1.1 1.10 1.21
[2,] 1.2 1.44 1.3 1.56 1.69
attr(,"degree")
[1] 1 2 1 2 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "poly"   "matrix"
> 
> # and gives the same
> t[1:2, ]
     1.0  2.0 0.1  1.1  0.2
[1,] 1.0 1.00 1.1 1.10 1.21
[2,] 1.2 1.44 1.3 1.56 1.69
> 
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ModelMatrixModel package. ModelMatrixModel() in  is similar to model.matrix(), but it save the transforming parameters, which can be applied new data.

```
library(ModelMatrixModel) 
traindf=data.frame(x1 = seq(1,  10,  by=0.2),
                   x2 = seq(1.1,10.1,by=0.2))

mm=ModelMatrixModel(~poly(x1,2)+poly(x2,3),traindf,sparse=F)
mm$x[1:2,] #output matrix
##   poly_x1__2_1 poly_x1__2_2 poly_x2__3_1 poly_x2__3_2 poly_x2__3_3
## 1   -0.2498843    0.3088653   -0.2498843    0.3088653   -0.3423492
## 2   -0.2387784    0.2676833   -0.2387784    0.2676833   -0.2510561
predict(mm,traindf[1:2,])$x
##   poly_x1__2_1 poly_x1__2_2 poly_x2__3_1 poly_x2__3_2 poly_x2__3_3
## 1   -0.2498843    0.3088653   -0.2498843    0.3088653   -0.3423492
## 2   -0.2387784    0.2676833   -0.2387784    0.2676833   -0.2510561
```