# How do I retrieve the equation of a 3D fit using lm()?

Tags: r, lm, polynomials

Suppose I have the following code to fit a hyperbolic parabola:

```
# attach(mtcars)    
hp_fit <- lm(mpg ~ poly(wt, disp, degree = 2), data = mtcars)
```

Where `wt` is the x variable, `disp` is the y variable, and `mpg` is the z variable. `(summary(hp_fit))$coefficients` outputs the following:

```
   >(summary(hp_fit))$coefficients
                                     Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept)                     22.866173   3.389734  6.7457122 3.700396e-07
    poly(wt, disp, degree = 2)1.0  -13.620499   8.033068 -1.6955539 1.019151e-01
    poly(wt, disp, degree = 2)2.0   15.331818  17.210260  0.8908534 3.811778e-01
    poly(wt, disp, degree = 2)0.1   -9.865903   5.870741 -1.6805208 1.048332e-01
    poly(wt, disp, degree = 2)1.1 -100.022013 121.159039 -0.8255431 4.165742e-01
    poly(wt, disp, degree = 2)0.2   14.719928   9.874970  1.4906301 1.480918e-01
```

I do not understand how to interpret the varying numbers to the right of `poly()` under the `(Intercept)` column. What is the significance of these numbers and how would I construct an equation for the hyperbolic paraboloid fit from this summary?

Comment: It won't be too hard if you use raw polynomials by setting `raw = TRUE` inside `poly()`. Using orthogonal polynomials is better for the stability of your regression, but the equation will be much more painful to extract. Related reading is [Extracting orthogonal polynomial coefficients from R's poly function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26729318/903061) and [How poly generates orthogonal polynomials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39051154/903061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare

```
with(mtcars, poly(wt, disp, degree=2))
with(mtcars, poly(wt, degree=2))
with(mtcars, poly(disp, degree=2))
```

the `1.0` `2.0` refer to the first and second degree of `wt`, and the `0.1` `0.2` refer to the first and second degree of `disp`. The `1.1` is an interaction term. You may check this by comparing:

```
summary(lm(mpg ~ poly(wt, disp, degree=2, raw=T), data=mtcars))$coe
#                                         Estimate  Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)                         4.692786e+01 7.008139762  6.6961935 4.188891e-07
# poly(wt, disp, degree=2, raw=T)1.0 -1.062827e+01 8.311169003 -1.2787937 2.122666e-01
# poly(wt, disp, degree=2, raw=T)2.0  2.079131e+00 2.333864211  0.8908534 3.811778e-01
# poly(wt, disp, degree=2, raw=T)0.1 -3.172401e-02 0.060528241 -0.5241191 6.046355e-01
# poly(wt, disp, degree=2, raw=T)1.1 -2.660633e-02 0.032228884 -0.8255431 4.165742e-01
# poly(wt, disp, degree=2, raw=T)0.2  2.019044e-04 0.000135449  1.4906301 1.480918e-01

summary(lm(mpg ~ wt*disp + I(wt^2) + I(disp^2) , data=mtcars))$coe[c(1:2, 4:3, 6:5), ]
#                  Estimate  Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  4.692786e+01 7.008139762  6.6961935 4.188891e-07
# wt          -1.062827e+01 8.311169003 -1.2787937 2.122666e-01
# I(wt^2)      2.079131e+00 2.333864211  0.8908534 3.811778e-01
# disp        -3.172401e-02 0.060528241 -0.5241191 6.046355e-01
# wt:disp     -2.660633e-02 0.032228884 -0.8255431 4.165742e-01
# I(disp^2)    2.019044e-04 0.000135449  1.4906301 1.480918e-01
```

This yields the same values. Note that I used `raw=TRUE` for comparison purposes.